# O que são hosts em uma rede de computadores?

Tags: redes

Todos os computadores ligados em uma rede são *hosts*, certo? Segundo a Wikipedia os *hosts* são hardwares que se comunicam com outros nós da rede, portanto um roteador pode ser considerado um *host*? E o que diferencia um *host* de um nó?

Outra coisa: Estudando sobre redes, vi que os roteadores tem internamente as tabelas de roteamento que permitem que ele vá direcionando os pacotes de ponto em ponto até chegar no seu destino final. O que seriam esses pontos da rede que os pacotes vão percorrendo? Por exemplo: se eu, que estou no Rio Grande do Sul, estou solicitando algo de um servidor que está em São Paulo, quais são esses pontos que ele passa? Quais são esses roteadores?

São dispositivos do meu provedor e de uma estrutura maior? São estes os nós?

EDIT: Links em português ou inglês que possam me explicar essas questões são bem vindos.

Comment: Votei para fechar como ampla porque, apesar de alguns temas serem "aceitáveis" no site, a maioria deles acredito necessitar explicar conceitos que podem acabar fugindo do escopo do site.

Comment: Oi @Articuno Pode me ajudar a torná-la adaptada ao site?

Comment: A primeira duvida acredito ser aceitavel, o restante acaba entrando em conceitos de hardware, que é totalmente fora do escopo do site

Comment: @Articuno , estou abrindo uma questão no meta sobre a salvação dessa pergunta, acredito que não seja tão _off topic_ nem tão ampla assim. Colo o link assim que tiver perguntado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado a maioria das questões entra em assuntos de hardware, apesar de ampliarmos o escopo, não é o foco adicionar hardware nele.

Comment: @Articuno, aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6390/64969

Comment: @Max estamos falando aqui de redes tcp/ip v4?

Comment: @Intruso Exatamente, Ipv4

Comment: Eu sou a favor de criar novas perguntas, uma para cada ponto específico desta pergunta. Seu conteúdo é salvável, mas não em uma única pergunta.

Comment: @max, olha a discussão sobre sua pergunta lá, veja se pode melhorar mais sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu to coçando aqui pra iniciar uma resposta, mas, tem umas coisas de redes ai que a galera vai estilar, a parte de protocolos é basicamente documentação sobre algoritmos de roteamento, as próprias RFCs já ajudam muito, mas, tem outras perguntas que são basicamente os conceitos de redes para entender os algoritmos, saca? Talvez se tentarmos direcionar mais aos protocolos/algoritmos e neles explorar os conceitos, sua pergunta entre para o escopo do site. De uma forma geral, o problema é que a pergunta tem muitas perguntas e não está com o foco em programação, sacas?

Comment: Talvez, sua pergunta seja melhor respondida aqui: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Na verdade minha pergunta era mais básica mesmo. Sei que o pessoal aqui preza pelo máximo de qualidade em tudo o que faz, mas eu não estava nem pensando em entrar nos detalhes técnicos e de engenharia. De toda forma, obrigado a todos até o momento

Comment: Max, aproveite a edição do Anderson e remova todas as outras duvidas, deixando apenas a relacionada ao titulo. A pergunta do titulo é aceitavel no site, Demais, quem for responder pode deixar referencias para você ler, pois isso não foge do escopo.

Comment: @Max o que o pessoal esta tentando dizer é que geralmente é ruim colocar muitas perguntas em um lugar só, porque acaba perdendo o foco e ficando muito abrangente. Você pode até pedir a pessoa para elucidar um caminho, mas, quanto mais objetiva a pergunta melhor.

Comment: @Intruso [Já tem lá um pergunta até](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/19445/)